# Convergence of specific power series

Tags: analysis, summation, power-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I have to evaluate pointwise/uniform/total convergence of this series and I didn't quite understand how to do it. 
$$\sum_{k=2}^{+\infty}{\ln k \over 2+\sin k}x^k$$
For pointwise convergence: it clearly diverges if $|x|\gt 1$ and converges if 
$x=0$.

**EDIT**: I managed to do everything else but still don't understand what happens in $x=-1$. Help?

Comment: Use a limit comparison test for $|x| < 1$, noting that $|\ln(n)| < t^n$ eventually for any $t > 1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I don't understand, how should I use this? If I replace $\ln k$ with $t^n$ I still have (the series)$\le$(series that doesn't converge)

Comment: If $|x| < r < 1$, take $t = r/|x|$. When $|\ln(k)| < t^k$, $$ \left|\frac{\ln(k) x^
k}{2+\sin(k)}\right| \le r^k$$ and $\sum_k r^k$ converges.

Comment: Regarding the **EDIT**: the term doesn't tend to zero, hence...